# representation theorem on the path space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, proof-verification

I'm working on a project and have done some work. However, there are some point where I'm unsure if my thoughts are correct. It would be appreciated if someone could share their thoughts about it.

Let $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}_+^K$. A general element $\omega\in \Omega$ is of the form $\omega=(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_K)$. Let $X:\Omega\to\Omega$ be the canonical process given by $X_k(\omega)=\omega_k$ and let $\mathcal{F}_k:=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_k)$. We are given a sequence of probability measures $P_n$ on $\Omega$ which converges weakly to $P$. Thus, by the Skorohod representation theorem there are $\Omega$-valued r.v. $(Y_n)$ and $Y_n$ on a probability space $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F},Q)$  such that $Y_n\to Y$ for every $\omega\in\Omega_2$ and

- $P_n=(Y_n)_*(Q)$ the law of $Y_n$ is $P_n$
- $P=(Y)_*(Q)$ the law of $Y$ is $P$

Now let $f$ be a fixed function and $(f_n)$ be a sequence of function with $f,f_n:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise. For the rest, $f$ and $(f_n)$ is fixed. Thus we have

$$E_P[f(X)]=\int_{\Omega}f(X(\omega))P(d\omega)=\int_{\Omega_2}f(X(Y(\omega')))Q(d\omega')=E_Q[f(X(Y))]$$

and in fact, since $X$ is the identity on $\Omega$, we have

$$E_P[f(X)]=E_Q[f(Y)]\tag{1}$$
in the same way we have

$$E_{P_n}[f_n(X)]=E_Q[f_n(Y_n)].\tag{2}$$

> **Question 1** Is my observation in $(1)$ and therefore $(2)$ correct?

My goal is to establish the following equality

$$E_P[f(X)]=\lim_nE_{P_n}E[f_n(X)]$$

We assume that $f(\omega)=\lim_nf_n(\omega_n)$ for all $\omega_n\to \omega$. Thus we have

$$E_Q[f(Y)]=E_Q[\lim_nf_n(Y_n)]=E_{P_n}[\lim_nf_n(X)] \tag{3}.$$

> **Question 2** Is my observation in $(3)$ correct?

Now if we can interchange limit and expectation we are done. So we need some further assumptions. 
If we assume that there is function $g$ such that for all $n$ we have the following:

$$E_{P_n}[g(X)] <\infty$$

and

$$|f_n(X)|\le g(X).$$

Note this is just a (random) integration condition. Thus we can use the dominated convergence to obtain

$$E_{P_n}[\lim_nf_n(X)]=\lim_n E_{P_n}[f_n(X)] \tag{4}.$$

> **Question 3** Is my observation in $(4)$ correct?

Comment: I am not sure about 3. If you fix f, sure, but what theorem are you applying to let n goes to infinity in both fn and Zn

Comment: @Lost1 Ah sorry, we fix a $f$ at the beginning. I edit my question.

Comment: Then you want to use m and n to distinguish them?

Comment: @Lost1 I'm not sure, since I really would like to have $P_n$ and $f_m$ the same, i.e. $f_m=P_n$. Reason: $f_n$ is a function from a domain, call it $A_n$ which depends on $n$ and we have for such function a bound, i.e. $E_{P_n}[f_n(X)]\le K+\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: What is $Z$?${}$

Comment: @StefanHansen Sorry that should be $Y$ and $Y_n$. I edited the question

Comment: @Lost1 Beside Question 3, would you agree with Question 1 and 2?

Comment: yes, i am still not convinced by 3.

Comment: @Lost1 Is this equality really true: $E_Q[\lim_nf_n(Y_n)]=E_{P_n}[\lim_n f_n(X)]$? The latter is then equal $E_{P_n}[\lim_n f_n]$ since $X$ is just the identity on $\Omega$